# Is there way to scroll to anchor rather than jump with javascript (something like smooth scroll)

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor

I have a large document with numbered anchor tags as shown below. And a textbox to punch the numbers in to go to anchor which uses **window.location.hash**

I am also using arrow keys to go next or previous anchors. I want to scroll to the anchor so to give some sense of direction.

```
<a name="1">
some text
<a name="2">
some text
<a name="3">
```

here is my function

```
function updatePageNumber()
{
    var pagenumber;
    pagenumber = document.getElementById('pageNumber').value;   
    window.location.hash =  pagenumber;
}
```

Jumping to anchor is very ugly and people loose sense of direction in the text. So is there a way to scroll to anchor with JavaScript. I know there are lots of jQuery examples, but I don't know jQuery and couldn't find JavaScript.

Most important reason is I want to see my page number on the address bar!

Comment: Chris Coyier of CSS tricks has got a working example http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ You will have to change your code accordingly

Answer (score 16):

Add jQuery library.

Use the following script to do a smooth scroll to the target element you want.

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#target').offset().top}, 1000);
```

`target` is the id of the target element and `1000` is the duration of the animation.

Comment: Not meaning to revive an old question, there is a bug in your solution; you need to reference the `top` of the `offset` object, not the offset itself. In other words: `jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#target').offset().top}, 1000);`

Comment: I took the liberty to apply @ean5533's bug fix as it is spot on. First, I just copy/pasted the answer's code; didn't work. Dam, started to look for something else. Later, saw the comment. Ups, it works!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code and enjoy**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btop").hide();  // replace only #btop with your <div id=" ">

$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>100){
            $('#btop').fadeIn();  // replace only #btop with your <div id=" ">
        }
        else{
            $('#btop').fadeOut(); // replace only #btop with your <div id=" ">
        }
    });

    $('#btop a').click(function(){ // replace only #btop with your <div id=" ">
        $('body,html').animate({
          scrollTop:0
        },200);  // to speed up scroll replace 200 to 300 or 500
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in smooth scrolling in JavaScript so you would have to implement it yourself -- but why re-invent the wheel if you already have it in [jQuery](http://www.jquery.org) and you probably won't have to add more than two or three lines of code? Just download jQuery and the [ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), add them to your `<head>` section in a `<script>` tag and then use this to scroll to an element with a given ID:

```
$.scrollTo("#my-element-id");
```

This will scroll to the element whose ID is `my-element-id` so you have to use the `id=...` attribute in the anchors and not the `name=...` attribute.

If you wish to add this behaviour automatically to all your anchors within a given `div` (or to the entire page), you can use the [LocalScroll plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) which makes the entire this as simple as:

```
$.localScroll();
```