# Smooth go top action via CSS

Tags: html, css

I designed a simple web site. It has both mobile & desktop views. It's actually done but I would like to add a little bit of animation, though I'm unable to achieve.

There is a 'go up' link at the bottom of the mobile site that let's the user to go straight to top. And I would like that link to perform that going up action smoothly rather than instantly.

I would also like to achieve this via CSS if possible with new attributes like animation-duration, etc. I couldn't figure out myself.

Here is the code in my HTML that let's the user to go to top:

```
<li class="top"><a href="#home"><span>⇧</span>Top</a></li>
```

What exactly should it's CSS be like to achieve what I need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there way to scroll to anchor rather than jump with javascript (something like smooth scroll)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451193/is-there-way-to-scroll-to-anchor-rather-than-jump-with-javascript-something-lik)

Comment: I don't think you can do this in CSS.  It would probably require a JavaScript solution.  This page I think can help.  View the demo and click on the "vertical scroll" link at the bottom.  I think that's what you're after. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

CSS is meant to set/change the **appearance** of your UI elements, not **navigation**. To make the site "scroll up" to be visible in the browser using CSS I imagine you could make an invisible element in the top expand all the way from top using a timed transition to move all the invisible part of your UI visible, and then hide or remove it...and even this way I doubt that you would be able to get there without JS.