# How do you set the starting section of my website in Grails/HTML

Tags: html, grails

I know you can create a link that will direct you to a section in your website like this

```
<a href="#result"></a>
```

But is it possible to set up your website that once it loads up, it automatically goes to the "#result" section? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to set the application root context to anchor to #result. How is this anyway related to Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a bit of JavaScript.
Put this in the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
function jumpTo(anchor){
    window.location.hash = '#' + anchor;
}
jumpTo('result');
</script>
```

If you have jQuery, you can also make it scroll -- it can make for better usability, cause the user then knows that he is viewing a part of a bigger page:

```
<script>
function jumpTo(anchor){
    var offset = $('a[name="' + anchor + '"]').offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 'fast');
}
jumpTo('result');
</script>
```

**Related:**

- [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)
- [Is there way to scroll to anchor rather than jump with javascript (something like smooth scroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451193/is-there-way-to-scroll-to-anchor-rather-than-jump-with-javascript-something-lik)

Comment: Oh! I upvoted your question, so there you go, you can vote now. :)

Comment: I noticed that haha. It did allow me to upvote yours now. Thanks :)